# Is it possible in Facebook for an app to post notifications only to users using that app?

Tags: facebook

I have an app which is not exclusive to use on Facebook. It is also (going to be) available on iPhones and Androids.

It's a social app, so, for example, an Android user would invite a friend in, and then they would send information back and forth between them.

In my Facebook interface, I want them to be able to do the same thing, but via the Facebook notification system. When a user makes a certain change in their system, that is shown on their wall.

The trouble is, due to the nature of my app - it's something only close friends would want to do with each other - I don't want that notification to appear to all the user's friends on Facebook. It should only appear to others who have also signed up for my app.

I'm having a little trouble conceptualizing how this would work. It seems to me that most apps broadcast to all friends, and then those friends can hide or not hide the notification. At best, it seems possible to put out an alert to say "user X has made a change in app Y", and then users who use that app can go into its particular interface and discover particular changes (which is less than ideal for what I want to do).

Can I make it so something appears as a notification and a wall posting only to people within my app space? If so, how?

*(If it makes a difference, my app is in Javascript with a PHP backend. Also, I am far from an expert on using Facebook, so please answer in a way a newbie can grasp. Thanks!)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different options you have for contacting the people who are using your application and their friends is covered in the [Social Channels](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/) doc.

As for contacting only the user's friends who are using the app, you have two options:

(1) Using the [graph api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) you can make a request to: *[/me/friends?fields=installed](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/friends%3Ffields%3Dinstalled)* which should return a list of users, the ones that have the app installed will have this form:

```
{
    "installed": true, 
    "id": "USER_ID"
}
```

The ones who don't have the app will be of this form:

```
{
    "id": "USER_ID"
}
```

(2) You can use [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) to check who are the friends who have the app installed using [this query](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20uid%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20not%20is_app_user%20and%20uid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me%28%29%29):

```
SELECT 
    uid
FROM 
    user 
WHERE 
    is_app_user 
    AND 
    uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I just thought I should mention that I am sure you are probably right, but as the whole Facebook notification system is new to me, I have been struggling to implement your advice. I just want to see that it works with my own eyes before marking it correct.

Comment: No prob. Also, the [Debug Tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) is made just for this kind of testing..